# Applying hotfix to intermediate commit on master

Tags: git, release-management, gitflow, merging

Below is the Gitflow workflow followed, where `master` branch has the commit history(`git tag`) of different releases.

From release mgmt aspect, we are deleting the `release` branch after merging with `master` and `develop` branch.

### [image]

To apply hot fix, we first `git checkout` a specific release commit from `master` branch and then create a hotfix branch from that specific commit(shown in orange, below) and make changes.

### [image]

**Questions:**

1) Does `git merge` allow hotfix branch to get merged to intermediate commit node(as shown below) on `master` branch? instead of merging to tip of `master`, because hotfix is for `0.1` release

[image]
2) If no, How to apply hotfix(of a specific release) through `master` branch?  because `release` branch is deleted

Comment: How long do you keep giving hotfix support on old releases?

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau Duration of a release in production environment is revenue driven, where customer is satisfied with functionality provided by that release

Comment: So, the hotfix will only exist in v 0.1 but not in 0.2 ?

Comment: @PieterB every release has production issues... so hotfix should be given through that release.

Comment: The issue I have is that you basically break the flow of the master "line". When looking at a commit history of your master they're points in time of the state of your code. Adding the hotfix to 0.1 breaks that line, there's no line between the second and third blue dot, because that third dot on your master reverts your hotfix. Dots represent "state" of codebase.

Comment: @PieterB So, if hotfix branch forked from v0.1 commit from `master` branch, then merging the hot fix(as shown in the last diagram) actually reverts the state of code in `master` branch from v1.0 to  (v0.1 + hotfix). Is that correct?

Answer (score 7):

You are actually asking how to manage multiple productive versions. Gitflow does not cover this and it's a complicated topic.

You can have a branch per supported version, e.g. version/1.9.0, and do a "nested gitflow" where you treat that version branch just like your master. This should work well enough until you want to back/forward port fixes.

Unfortunately, i don't have any experience with that so cannot help more than this.

---

To answer the literal question:

This is not possible. One could rebase all of the following history, but that creates so many inconveniences and troubles that it's not an option.

Answer (score 4):

As marstato says you'll need multiple version branches to be able to support multiple minor (or major) releases. Along side to these version branches you'll have fix branches. You don't really have a master branch anymore.

So in your situation you have a version/0.1, version/0.2 and version/0.3 branch. And a fix/0.1, fix/0.2 and fix/0.3 branch. When there is a bug found in the 0.1 version you apply that fix on the fix/0.1 branch, merge that fix branch into version/0.1 and in fix/0.2. Then you merge fix/0.2 in version/0.2 and fix/0.3 (and so on). Finally you merge your last fix branch in its corresponding version and branch and into your develop branch.

When you no longer need to support a version you can delete the version and fix branch of that version and skip them when merging.

Be advised that this introduces a lot of overhead, certainly when supporting a lot of versions. You can reduce the overhead by only periodicaly merging fix branches, but that introduces the problem of having your testing team to know which hotfix has been merged already in which version.

Below you'll find a short example with a version 0.1 and 0.2.

[image: Example of the proces described above]

Comment: Is it not better to not delete release branch and then create hotfix branch through release branch?

Comment: Not entirely sure what you mean. You only want to delete a release branch when youré no longer interested in that minor version. The fix branch will always exist as it will be merged into other fix branches (or into develop). That I should probably place into the answer as well.

Comment: **1)** When you say: *you'll need multiple version branches*, are you referring to multiple `release` branches forked from `develop` branch? **2)** When you say: *you have a version/0.1 branch*, do you mean, `release 0.1` branch forked from `develop` branch?

Comment: You can indeed name them relaese branches, they however are not forked from develop. but from a previous release branch. As you can see in the example the version/0.2 branch and the fix/0.1 branch were created when 0.1.1 was released.

Comment: From which branch v0.1 `release` branch forked from?

Comment: Your initial commit would be on the release/0.1 branch -> probably master. I don't use master in this case as there realy isn't a master branch anymore as you don't have one version. Each release/ branch is kindof a master branch where you apply gitflow on (that's what marsato refers to as "nested gitflow")

Answer (score 1):

Your basic question is to *inject* a commit into the commit history, which is a lot like rewriting the Git history. You can do this with `rebase interactive`. Beware, you may have merge conflicts to deal with. See here:

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History

See the section on **Reordering Commits**. Without knowing your exact commit history, it won't be possible to provide the commands needed. So, I will simply quote the web link above:

> **Reordering Commits**
>
> You can also use interactive rebases to reorder or remove commits
> entirely. If you want to remove the “Add cat-file” commit and change
> the order in which the other two commits are introduced, you can
> change the rebase script from this:

```
pick f7f3f6d Change my name a bit
pick 310154e Update README formatting and add blame
pick a5f4a0d Add cat-file
```

> to this:

```
pick 310154e Update README formatting and add blame
pick f7f3f6d Change my name a bit
```

> When you save and exit the editor, Git rewinds your branch to the
> parent of these commits, applies `310154e` and then `f7f3f6d`, and then
> stops. You effectively change the order of those commits and remove
> the “Add cat-file” commit completely.